# I’ve noticed i’ve started losing a good bit of money since I bought Plazas and Promenades for Cities: Skylines. Why?

Tags: cities-skylines

As the title suggests, i’ve noticed i’ve been losing tax revenue since I bought and used the Plazas and Promenades DLC for Cities: Skylines and i’m not quite sure why or how to fix it.  I’ve set my taxes to the maximum tolerable limit (12%).

My theory is that there’s a game mechanic that, because there is little vehicle traffic, i’m not generating income at a fast enough rate. I’m on xbox and I don’t use any mods.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My best guess would be that there is a balance patch that comes with that DLC, and a strategy that you maybe unconciously use has been nerfed hard. But I dont know enough to say what or why.